# I can't include while loop inside of a variable

Tags: php, variables

I have a string :

```
<?
$home = '<ul>
<li>
first line
</li>
// Here I want to write some while loop//
<li>
second line
</li>
</ul>';

    // somewhere on the bottom of the page I echo $home                     

?>
```

I can't seperate home variable to include while loop code between it
I have tried to seperate in with `'; echo '`
but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but you should learn basic coding if you can't figure this out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is concatenate the first part of the string with the results from the while loop and then with the last part of the string. Such as:

```
<?php 

   while() {} // return results

   $home = '<ul><li>first line</li>' . $results . '<li>second line</li></ul>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't loop inside a variable

instead try to

```
<ul>

<li></li>

<?php 

while($flag) { 

 // do stuff and make sure you mark $flag as false 
 // otherwise it will loop for ever
 // the idea is to break the loop after you did what you need to do

} 

?>

<li></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

try separating your variable into different parts like :

```
<?
$home = '<ul><li>first line</li>';

while(something is true) {

   $home .= "This will end up in the middle of your variable content";

}

$home .= '<li>second line</li></ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Not the prettiest solution, but he said he wanted a while loop within a variable, this seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$home = '<ul><li>first line</li>';

while(something is true) {

   $home .= "This will end up in the middle of your variable content";

}

$home .= '<li>second line</li></ul>';
?>
```